# Highcharts.js : get specific value from data to tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization, interactive, donut-chart

I want to make a Highcharts donut chart based on [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/NVX3S/147/). Only that my data would look something like this:

```
data: [
                {y:40, color: colors[0], name: 'yoyo'},
                {y:0, color: colors[1],  name: 'dada'},
                {y:60, color: colors[2],  name: 'sasa'}
            ]
```

Now: when I change the `mouseOver` function to this:

```
mouseOver: function(){
                        this.series.chart.innerText.attr({text: this.name});
                    },
```

Then I am able to retrieve the value of the the `name`-key from my data. However, when I want to add it to a tooltip, the following code does not work (code is added after `tooltip:` in the original code):

```
{
      formatter: function() {
                             return '<b>'+this.name+'</b>';
                    }
                },
```

When I change `this.name` to `this.y` then I again get the correct value. Could anyone please tell me how to retrieve `this.name` for the tooltip? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: In a formatter callback this is not a point object, but it has some attributes of the associated point. So you can use this.key or this.point.name.

Comment: aha, thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your formatter by :

```
formatter: function() {
    return '<b>' + this.key + '</b>';
}
```

When you don't know how is your object, use `console.log(myObject)` in your code and check your js console.